# How to apply "if event target" in jQuery for div and apply to all childen as well (modal close issue)?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, parent-child

I have a typical modal setup on a page. You press a button to activate. The screen darkens (via a full screen background div) and the modal is front of it (highest z-index).

I also have it set typically where you can either press the close button or anywhere outside of the main modal, to close it.

This all works fine when if the modal is empty.

Issue: When you click on any child content within the modal (text, divs, etc) this also is closing the modal.

Below is my code that is suppose to ignore clicks inside #modal, but it is not applying it to all of the child content within it.

*#blackout represents the semi transparent full screen div behind the main modal (common modal effect).*

```
$("#blackout").click(function(event){
if(event.target === modal){
return false;
}
else{
$("#blackout").css( 'display', 'none');
} 
});
```

Is there a way to change the code so that the if statement applies to modal, and anything inside of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem myself.  Perhaps this will be helpful to others.

Assuming your main modal div is #modal, adding the following code will still allow functionality of links, etc on child elements inside the modal but will avoid unwanted closing of the modal when doing so.

```
$("#modal").click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
});
```